# How to manipulate URL param in Slim 4 Framework?

Tags: url-parameters, slim-4

I'm using Slim4 for my website and my routes have this format:

**http://mywebsite/page/{pageid}**

For SEO purposes I want to switch them to

**http://mywebsite/page/{pageid}_free_text**
for example:
**http://mywebsite/page/123465_my_page_title**

Of course I have many other routes with this root:
**http://mywebsite/page/{pageid}_free_text/comments

http://mywebsite/page/{pageid}_free_text/comment/{commentid}/view**
...

I would like to not refactor all my callbacks param handling but just replace at once with a regular expression the param named "pageid" from **123465_my_page_title** to **123456**, so I can keep all callbacks as they are.

Is it possibile to do it somehow? Is it possibile to manipulate the params array maybe with a Middleware?